# Adding easing to animateKeyframes

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm animating the scale of a button using `animateKeyframes` in Swift 3 using the following code:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 4, delay: 1, options: [.repeat, .allowUserInteraction, .calculationModeCubic], animations: {
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.myButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1,y: 1)
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.1, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.myButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9,y: 0.9)
            })
            }, completion: nil)
```

What I need to do is add easing to each keyframe. I looked up something that uses the following code that can then be passed to `animateKeyframes`

```
let animationOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = .curveEaseIn
let keyframeAnimationOptions: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions = UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationOptions.rawValue)
```

However, it doesn't quite say exactly how to pass the keyframeAnimationOptions variable, and I can't seem to figure it out myself! Can anybody help?

Comment: @Ekta Padaliya, user1391152 I am facing some issue like, in my app I am showing waves animation like siri does, but if i press any other object, animation getting halt and after I release touch, its again doing animation, can you help me in that to fix?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this one?

Answer (score -3):

You can use below code to call the keyframeAnimationOptions variable.

```
let keyframeAnimationOption=UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModeCubic

UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: keyframeAnimationOption, animations:
    {
                    /////Your code //////

    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: OP is working with Swift3 batter if you post answer in Swift 3

Comment: If you read the question he states that each keyframe must have a different timing.